# NSView -drawRect and mouse hover performance

Tags: macos, performance, cocoa, quartz-graphics

I have a custom NSView that draws (with `-drawRect`) a graph.  It also tracks the mouse position (with `-mouseMoved` and the like) and draws the cursor position/coordinates relative to the axes.

The graph is big and (potentially) slow to draw, and doesn't depend on the mouse position.  The mouse-over effect is tiny, and always fast to draw.  I don't want to have to redraw everything when the mouse moves a couple pixels, because it feels sluggish.

I'm sure I can make my own private graphics context (doubled in size, if on a 2x display), draw the chart data into that once, and then have `-drawRect` simply blit that into the view's drawing context.  Alternatively, I could split my NSView subclass into two classes, and have one just the chart data, and one just the overlay, and place them exactly on top of each other (though they have to share a bit of data, so this seems awkward).

Is there a built-in method to make this easier, or is there a more idiomatic way of handling this?

Comment: It depends quite a bit on the effect you are going for.  If it's going to be embedded in the window, these days you might want to just use a `CALayer` for the overlay.  In the "old days" we'd create a real window and anchor it to the NSView at the specific location and move it around with the mouse.  With `CALayer`s, the underlying `CALayer` is cached separately and won't redraw when the overview layer is moved on top of it.

Comment: You can always redraw a smaller rect by calling 'setNeedsDisplayInRect:' and use a rect around the cursor.

Comment: gaige: I'll take a look at CALayer, thanks.

Comment: TheAmateurProgrammer: Only if the cursor drawing area is restricted to a region into which the graph is easily segmented (it's not).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these NSWindow methods:

Bracketing Drawing Operations
– cacheImageInRect:
– restoreCachedImage
– discardCachedImage

Normally, with a view, you define a drawRect: method that draws contents on-demand. You can, however, do on the spot drawing in a view as result of events for example, by locking focus on the view, performing the drawing, then unlocking focus. The missing link in this on-the-spot drawing, is somehow undoing it without calling your potentially heavy drawRect: via setNeedsDisplay:

This is where the Bracketed drawing operations on NSWindow come into play. Before locking focus on the view and doing some on-the-spot drawing, cache an image of the view in the area you intend to draw. When you next want to update your drawing (while tracking events, perhaps) then restore the cached image, rinse, and repeat.